# Android Gestures, Single stroke & Multi-stroke produce inconsistent results

Tags: java, android, xml, gestures

[image: + - × /]

I'm having a really weird problem while following the Gestures tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html.

4 unique gestures are created in Gesture Builder: + - × /

Add and multiply are multi-stroke. Subtract and divide are single stroke.

The Activity loads the pre-built GestureLibrary (R.raw.gestures), adds an OnGesturePerformedListener to the GestureOverlayView, and ends with onGesturePerformed() when a gesture is detected & performed.

**Activity layout in XML**

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gestures"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
/>
```

**Located in onCreate()**

```
    mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!mLibrary.load()) {
        finish();
    }

    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

**Located in onGesturePerformed()**

```
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

    // We want at least one prediction
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);

        // We want at least some confidence in the result
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
            // Show the spell
            Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The main problem is the pre-built gestures are not being recognized correctly. For example, onGesturePerformed() is never performed if a horizontal gesture is followed by a vertical (addition). The method *is* called if a vertical gesture is followed by a horizontal. This is how GesturesListDemo behaves too ([GesturesDemos.zip @ code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/downloads/detail?name=GesturesDemos.zip&can=2&q=)).

Furthermore, the predicted gesture ends up being the incorrect gesture. Add is recognized as subtract; multiply as divide; Subtract as add. It's completely inconsistent.

Finally, add and subtract gestures typically share similar Prediction.score's, which is weird since they differ by an entire stroke.

Sorry about the long post -- wanted to be thorough. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a really old question, but it hasn't been answered yet and this might help someone. I just came across a similar problem and my solution was to use `gesture.getStrokesCount()` to differentiate between single- and multi-stroke gestures.

Example:

```
ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

// We want at least one prediction
if (predictions.size() > 0) {
    Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);

    // We want at least some confidence in the result
    if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
        if (gesture.getStrokesCount() > 1) {
            // This is either add or multiply
        }
        else {
            // This is either subtract or divide
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I've added further implementation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Drew Lederman his answer, you can use this implementation of onGesturePerformed to always get the best result:

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {

        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = store.recognize(gesture);
        double highScore = 0;
        String gestureName = "";

        for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {

            if (prediction.score > SCORE && prediction.score > highScore && 
                    store.getGestures(prediction.name).get(0).getStrokesCount() == gesture.getStrokesCount()) {

                highScore = prediction.score;
                gestureName = prediction.name;

            }
        }
        // Do something with gestureName
    }
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm just trying out some things with this. The list of predictions appears to be sorted, so you're better off just breaking after you've found one as no predictions after it will be better.

Comment: @PMunch I didn't know this. This means we don't need 'highScore' either.

Comment: that was my point. I implemented a top three thing by decreasing a counter for each hit, made it really easy that it was pre-sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, are supported, at least from Android 2.3.3. But it is heavily imprecise. [Check the second example](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html).